# how i do infinite scrolling by using polymer paper-scroll-header-panel?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

i am using Polymer-1.0 paper-scroll-header-panel & looking auto-loading of content when user reach bottom (like facebook's infinite scrolling), the code given below working perfectly

```
listeners: {
"content-scroll": "scroll"
},

scroll: function(e, d){
console.log(e, d);
},
```

but how i know user reach bottom of page & is there any threshold setup available (like 80% from top) ?

in `d.target' object`scrollHeight`&`scrollTop` are available, but i don't know how i use these value for infinite scrolling

Comment: @529 in https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-scroll-header-panel/blob/master/paper-scroll-header-panel.html  may provide insight on the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scroll: function(e, d) {
    if (d.target.scrollHeight - (d.target.clientHeight * 1.5) < d.target.scrollTop) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

i don't know this is the right way but it will work, tested in chrome & firefox